# Pass Parameter with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is there any way i can pass parameters with UITapGestureRecognizer?
I've seen this answered for objective-c but couldn't find an answer for swift

```
test.userInteractionEnabled = true
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped4:"))
// Something like text.myParamater
test.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

And then receive myParameter under func imageTapped4(){}

Answer (score 61, accepted):

One approach would be to subclass UITapGestureRecognizer and then set a property, I've posted an example below. You could also do some check on the sender and check if equal to some tag, class, string, e.t.c

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        image.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        let tappy = MyTapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)))
        image.addGestureRecognizer(tappy)
        tappy.title = "val"
    }

    func tapped(sender : MyTapGesture) {
        print(sender.title)
        label1.text = sender.title
    }
}

class MyTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var title = String()
}
```

There are lots of examples on SO, have a look, good luck.

Comment: Thanx! That was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 20):

### For Swift 4

In Viewdidload

```
let label     =   UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: h, width: Int(self.phoneNumberView.bounds.width), height: 30))
                label.textColor = primaryColor
                label.numberOfLines = 0
                label.font = title3Font
                label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                label.attributedText = fullString

 let phoneCall = MyTapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(self.openCall))
        phoneCall.phoneNumber = "\(res)"
            label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            label.addGestureRecognizer(phoneCall)
```

Function as

```
@objc func openCall(sender : MyTapGesture) {
        let number = sender.phoneNumber
        print(number)
}
```

Write Class as

```
class MyTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var phoneNumber = String()
}
```

### Follow Step Properly and make change according to your variable , button ,label . It WORKS PROPERLY

Answer (score 0):

Without subclassing, you can also add the parameter in the view layer (where the gesture is attached):

```
let tappy = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)))
image.addGestureRecognizer(tappy)
image.layer.setValue(title, forKey: "anyKeyName")
```

Later in the handler

```
@objc private func tapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let title = sender.view?.layer.value(forKey: "anyKeyName") as? String else { return }
    // Do something with the title
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to determind the parameter when the func `imageTapped64`is fired. You can get you params via the view (take a look to @Developer Sheldon answer) 
or in many other ways.

Answer (score -1):

There is a NSString* name property for debugging available for misuse:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/2890966-name?language=objc

```
- (void)handleTapOnLink:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   NSString *url = sender.name;
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```