# How do I add an identifier to the UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimageview

I have an array with separate UIImages and I am displaying them using an UIImageView, how do I add an identifier to them so that I can switch to the view controller with the specific data related to that image.

Below is the code:

```
class Orders2ViewController: UIViewController, OrdersBaseCoordinated {

    var orderList: [OrderInfo] = [OrderInfo( itemImage: UIImage(named: "printer.jpeg")!, itemSKU: 12567), OrderInfo(itemImage: UIImage(named: "ipad.jpeg")!, itemSKU: 34521), OrderInfo( itemImage: UIImage(named: "hoodie.jpeg")!, itemSKU: 93620)]

    lazy var someImageView: UIImageView = {
    let theImageView = UIImageView()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Orders2ViewController.tappedMe))
    theImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    theImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    theImageView.image = orderList[selectedIndex].itemImage
           theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           return theImageView
        }()

    @objc func tappedMe(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        coordinator?.passImageData(j: )
    }
```

I want to pass an identifier in my tappedMe function to recognize which image was tapped on, I did find other answers on SO that mentioned gesture.view.tag but I don't want to create another view, rather navigate to the next controller with an identifier. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about subclassing UITapGestureRecognizer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38446852/9629494

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since UIImageView inherits from UIView, you can use it’s parameter called `tag`. In your example you can set `theImageView.tag = orderedList[selectedIndex].itemSKU`. Then each time tap was recognized, you can just use this `itemSKU` to do move to the next screen.

However it seems that you have only one UIImageView on the screen and you use `selectedIndex` to determine which image you need. So you can just do like that:

```
@objc func tappedMe(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    coordinator?.passImageData(j: orderList[selectedIndex].itemImage)
}
```

I passed the `itemImage` just to show you how it can be done. You can use whatever you need.